# How to expose a property from a fluent interface with boost::python?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have a C++ class which presents a *fluent* interface, something like:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    int bar() const { return m_bar; };
    Foo& bar(int value) { m_bar = value; return *this; };

  private:
    int m_bar;
};
```

I'd like to wrap the `bar()` functions as a property in my Python class. So I wrote:

```
class_<Foo>("Foo")
  .add_property(
    "bar",
    (int (Foo::*)())&Foo::bar,
    (Foo& (Foo::*)(int))&Foo::bar
  )
;
```

But the compiler complains about the setter, because it returns a `Foo&` instead of just `void`.

I can probably use `make_function` to specify a *call policy* but here I'm stuck: I don't know which policy to specify (I don't even know if such a policy exists).

What can I do to solve this ?

Here is the compiler output:

> `/usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:88: error: no match for call to '(const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<Foo&>) (Foo&)'`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writting the following template function:

```
template <class BaseClass, typename T, BaseClass& (BaseClass::*method)(T)>
void make_nonfluent_setter(BaseClass& self, T value)
{
    (self.*method)(value);
}
```

And now I can type:

```
class_<Foo>("Foo")
  .add_property(
    "bar",
    (int (Foo::*)())&Foo::bar,
    make_nonfluent_setter<Foo, int, &Foo::bar>
  )
;
```

And it works fine :)